# List of type T to Dictionary

Tags: c#, list, dictionary

I have an object `List<T>` and a keyfieldName of Type `T` i am trying to convert this `List<T>` to an `Dictionary<string,double>`

for example if Type T is of type Person, i will be given `keyfieldName ="UserId"`

```
ListItem1==>    Person
        UserId  1
        Firstname : "John"
        Lastname    "Doe"
ListItem2==>    Person
        UserId  2
        Firstname : "Mark"
        Lastname    "Twain"
ListItem3==>    Person
        UserId  27
        Firstname : "Hello"
        Lastname    "Life"
```

the result I am expecting would be `Dictionary<string,double>`, idea is take each property in Type `T` take its value and append it with :keyfieldName. keyfieldName by itself is excluded from dictionary. All of the property inside Type `T` would have to be converted to string.

Dictionary should look like this:

```
"John:1",0
"Doe:1",0
"Mark:2",0
"Twain:2",0
"Hello:27",0
"Life:27",0
```

What I have tried so far is to loop:

```
FieldInfo Idfield = typeof(T).GetField(HashKeyFieldName);
foreach (var item in indexItems)
{
    string keyvalue = Idfield.GetValue(item).ToString();

    foreach (var f in typeof(T).GetFields().Where(f => f.Name != HashKeyFieldName))
    {
        string obj =f.GetValue(item).ToString() + ":" + keyvalue;
    }
}
```

I noticed that `List` has `ToDictionary` function; I was wondering if it can be done faster and better, and if so, how?

Comment: What's the problem with using `ToDictionary`?

Comment: This feels like a pretty odd sort of situation, to be honest. How many properties are you likely to be dealing with in reality?

Comment: problem with toDictonary is i do not know the type in advance., to dictionary expects prpertyname

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the type in advance, I'd just use:

```
var dictionary = list.Select(x => x.FirstName + ":" + x.UserId)
                     .Concat(list.Select(x => x.LastName + ":" + x.UserId))
                     .ToDictionary(p => p, p => 0);
```

There'll be one extra `Concat` call per additional property, but that shouldn't be too bad - again, *if* you know the class in advance. If you really need to do this with reflection, then the code you've got already is roughly what I'd use - although I'd strongly advise you to use properties rather than fields.

Comment: what is the advantage of using  typeof(T).GetProperties() vs using  typeof(T).GetFields()

Comment: @JustinHomes: I view fields as an implementation detail - they should almost always be private, and their names should be irrelevant. Properties (and methods etc) are how you should define your public interface to a type - that way you can change your implementation details (how the properties are represented internally) without changing your public API.